# Update a Localtime object from LocalTime.of() method on the java console

Tags: java, localtime

I'm having a little issue here if anyone could help me with it I would really appreciate it !

When I try to update a `LocalTime` object created from the `LocalTime.now()` method so I can see time passing, **it works** here is the code :

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalTime d = LocalTime.now();
        String h = String.valueOf(d.getHour());
        String m = String.valueOf(d.getMinute());
        String s = String.valueOf(d.getSecond());
        System.out.print("\r"+h + ":" + m + ":" + s);

        //Update :
        Thread.sleep(1000);


     }
```

Output :

```
1:53:2 (time is passing)
```

But when I run this :

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalTime d = LocalTime.of(12, 15, 33);
        String h = String.valueOf(d.getHour());
        String m = String.valueOf(d.getMinute());
        String s = String.valueOf(d.getSecond());
        System.out.print("\r"+h + ":" + m + ":" + s);

        //Update :
        Thread.sleep(1000);


     }
```

Output :

```
12:15:33 (time is not passing)
```

Can someone tell me why it's not updating ? And how can I get time running with a `LocalTime` object from a user input ?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: `When I try to update a LocalTime object` - there is no update code - what do you mean?

Comment: Clueless on what you are asking: you are explicitly creating a LocalTime of 12:15:33 (`LocalTime.of(12, 15, 33)` ) and it is giving you this result.  What's the problem on that?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I mean updating the time on the console

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean - please show the code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I showed you the code ! Copy it and past it on your IDE and you'll get what I mean :)

Comment: `LocalTime d = LocalTime.of(12, 15, 33);` is the date you are requesting - why should it print something else - that would be very strange wouldn't it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes but what I'm looking for is displaying in the console the time passing starting 12:15:33 which I cannot do using `LocalTime.of(12, 15, 33)`.

Comment: But that is not the time, why would you want to do that.  Your code does not show anything like this.  Are we just supposed to guess what you want?

Comment: `LocalTime.now();` gets the real time as of now, in the real world where most of us live.  As time does as actually move at the speed of 1 second per second, if you wait for 5 seconds and call `now` again, the date will have moved by 5 seconds.

Comment: I posted a Question eventually raised by the OP, quite different than the original Questions asked here: [*Using java.time.Clock.offset to increment in time with an arbitrary starting time-of-day*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58637015/642706)

Comment: Your `d` isn’t updating in the first snippet either. Try printing before and after waiting a second (or longer). You will get the same output both times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Static, not dynamic

> Can someone tell me why it's not updating ?

A `LocalTime` represents a particular time of day. The object is immutable, unchanging, and cannot be updated.

Calling `LocalTime.now()` captures the time of day at that moment of execution. The value will *not* change later. To get the current time of day *later*, call `LocalTime.now()` again for a fresh new object.

To display the value of a `LocalTime` object, call `.toString` to generate text in standard ISO 8701 value. For other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter`. Search to learn more as this has been handled many times already.

## Elapsed time

> And how can I get time running with a LocalTime object from a user input ?

Perhaps you mean you want to determine the amount of time that has elapsed since an earlier moment, such as when the user last performed a particular act or gesture.

> so I can see time passing

For elapsed time, you need to track a moment rather than a time-of-day. The `Instant` class represents a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Calculate elapsed time on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds with a `Duration`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( instant , Instant.now() ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, regarding the elapsed time, I'm not really looking for an elapsed time, what I'm looking for is getting data from a user (hours, minutes and seconds) and displaying time running within the console starting the time the user has given (I don't know if it's clear enough to be honest, I hope you get my point !). Thanks for your time once again !

Comment: @tanjamaro Nope, not clear. Your explanations are creating more confusion. Please rethink the problem, and revise your Question. And next time practice writing a draft of your question *before* posting.

Comment: Well I don't understand whats unclear haha, maybe I misspelled some words, truly sorry for that ! Can you try reading the comment again please ?

Comment: For one thing, “displaying time running within the console starting the time the user has given” makes no sense. The console part seems irrelevant. And “time running” involves the current time, not some arbitrarily entered time. I too am voting to close this Question as unclear.

Comment: Let's take an example : if the user gives the string "14:55:20" to the program, the program should display "14:55:20", "14:55:21" etc ..

Comment: @tanjamaro So you want to make up an imaginary clock? That is not at all what you asked.

Comment: @tanjamaro This seems to precisely answer your question.  You wanted to know why a LocalDate object doesn’t change over time, did you not?

Comment: @tanjamaro For an imaginary clock, see this Question: [*Using java.time.Clock.offset to increment in time with an arbitrary starting time-of-day*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58637015/642706)

Comment: @BasilBourque this is actually what I was looking for thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a clock that updates starting at a certain time try something like

```
LocalTime d = LocalTime.of(12, 15, 33);
LocalTime start = LocalTime.now();

for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
    Duration dur = Duration.between(start, now);
    start = now;
    d = d.plusSeconds(dur.getSeconds());
    System.out.println(d);
}
```