# Using java.time.Clock.offset to increment in time with an arbitrary starting time-of-day

Tags: java, clock

I want a clock that is set to an arbitrary time-of-day, then ticks in one-second increments.

For example, start with "14:55:20". Then my app should output "14:55:20", "14:55:21", "14:55:22" and so on in one-second ticks.

It would seem that [`Clock.offset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#offset(java.time.Clock,java.time.Duration)) is meant to do just this. To quote the doc:

> Obtains a clock that returns instants from the specified clock with the specified duration added

So I tried the following:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse( "14:55:20" );
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ).with( localTime );
Duration duration = Duration.between( odt.toInstant() , Instant.now() );
Clock clock = Clock.offset( Clock.systemUTC() , duration );

System.out.println( "odt = " + odt );
System.out.println( "duration = " + duration );

for ( int i = 1 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
{
    LocalTime lt = OffsetDateTime.now( clock ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ).toLocalTime();
    System.out.println( "localTime = " + lt );
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis( 1 ) );
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My initial starting point with `odt` seems right. But then my calls to `OffsetDateTime.now( clock )` are not producing the desired outcome.

> odt = 2019-10-31T14:55:20Z
>
> duration = PT-10H-29M-4.832902S
>
> localTime = 17:57:10
>
> localTime = 17:57:11
>
> localTime = 17:57:12

➥ I am I not properly using `Clock.offset`? Or am I misunderstanding some concept here?

Comment: As a solution to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58635651/update-a-localtime-object-from-localtime-of-method-on-the-java-console ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Actually, [that Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58635651/642706) as written is [already solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58635678/642706). After many comments, the author of that Question revealed an entirely different question. Indeed, this Question here resulted from my failed attempt at solving that entirely different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration is the wrong way:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( Instant.now(), odt.toInstant() ); // Flipped arguments
```

*Output*

```
odt = 2019-10-31T14:55:20Z
duration = PT8H1M41.0216146S
localTime = 14:55:20
localTime = 14:55:21
localTime = 14:55:22
localTime = 14:55:23
localTime = 14:55:24
localTime = 14:55:25
localTime = 14:55:26
localTime = 14:55:27
localTime = 14:55:28
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can simply check if the number of second have changed, for example you can do this :

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // hour of launch
        String startTime = getTime();
        // actual time;
        String time = getTime();
        // elapsed time in seconds.
        int elapsedTime = 0;

        while (true) {
            if(!time.equals(getTime())) {
                time = getTime();
                // Output actual time.
                System.out.println(time);
                elapsedTime += 1;         
            }
        }               
    }

    public static String getTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date); 
    }
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat`? `Date`? *Please*, don't use those classed, they're declared obsolete a long time ago. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.